# The max count of layers in QOpenGLFunctions and QOpenGLFunctions_4_3_Core

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

In my program, if use QOpenGLTexture, I can set 256 layers texture like this:

```
    texture= new QOpenGLTexture(QOpenGLTexture::Target2DArray);
    texture->create();
    texture->setSize(24,24);
    texture->setLayers(256);
    texture->setFormat(QOpenGLTexture::RGB8_UNorm);
    texture->allocateStorage();
```

and set data for each layer(mem_texture is void* where texture data stored):

```
for(int i=0;i<256;i++)
    {
        texture->setData(0,i,QOpenGLTexture::RGBA,QOpenGLTexture::UInt8,((const char*)((uint)mem_texture+offset)));
        offset+=0x900;
    }
```

The result is good.But if I use original API like this:

```
    GLuint colorPattern;
    glGenTextures(1, &colorPattern);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, colorPattern);
    glTexStorage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 1, GL_RGB8, 24, 24,256);
    glTexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY,0,0,0,0,24,24,256,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,mem_texture);
    free(mem_texture);
```

I find that I can only use 128 layers textures at most.What is the differences between this two methods? How can use original OpenGL API to set 256 layers of textures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When set the z value of texture cords, I use GL_BYTE, in fact I should use GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE.